# In Python, count the number of variables in a class or prevent adding new class variables

Tags: python, class, variables, count

In python, is there a way to prevent adding new class variables after defining the object?

For example:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3

bar = foo()
try:
    bar.d = 4
except Exception, e:
    print "I want this to always print"
```

Alternatively, is there a way to count the number of variables in an object?

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3
    def count(self):
        ...

bar = foo()
if bar.count() == 3:
    print "I want this to always print"
```

The only way I thought of doing this was using a dictionary or list:

```
class foo:
    def __int__(self):
        self.dict = {'foo':1, 'bar':2} 
        self.len  = 2
    def chk():
        return self.len == len(self.list)
```

However, doing this feels rather cumbersome for python.  (obj.dict['foo']).  I'd prefer just obj.foo if possible.

I want to have this so that I never accidentally declare a variable when I mean to change an existing one.

```
f = foo()
f.somename = 3
...
f.simename = 4 #this is a typo

if f.somename == 3:
    solve_everything()
```

Comment: Thank you all for your prompt and helpful replies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using `__setattr__` to avoid the oddities of `__slots__`.

You always have to be careful when messing with `__setattr__`, since it takes care of setting *all* instance attributes, including those you set in `__init__`. Therefore it has to have some way of knowing when to allow the setting of an attribute, and when to deny it. In this solution I've designated a special attribute that controls whether new attributes are allowed or not:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3
        self.freeze = True

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if getattr(self, "freeze", False) and not hasattr(self, attr):
            raise AttributeError("You shall not set attributes!")
        super(A, self).__setattr__(attr, value)
```

Testing:

```
a = A()
try:
    a.d = 89
except AttributeError:
    print "It works!"
else:
    print "It doesn't work."
a.c = 42
print a.a
print a.c
a.freeze = False
a.d = 28
a.freeze = True
print a.d
```

Result:

```
It works!
1
42
28
```

Also see [gnibblers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11965358/566644) that wraps this concept neatly up in a class decorator, so it doesn't clutter up the class definition and can be reused in several classes without duplicating code.

---

**EDIT:**

Coming back to this answer a year later, I realize a context manager might solve this problem even better. Here's a modified version of gnibbler's class decorator:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def declare_attributes(self):
    self._allow_declarations = True
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        self._allow_declarations = False

def restrict_attributes(cls):
    cls.declare_attributes = declare_attributes
    def _setattr(self, attr, value):
        disallow_declarations = not getattr(self, "_allow_declarations", False)
        if disallow_declarations and attr != "_allow_declarations":
            if not hasattr(self, attr):
                raise AttributeError("You shall not set attributes!")
        super(cls, self).__setattr__(attr, value)
    cls.__setattr__ = _setattr

    return cls
```

And here's how to use it:

```
@restrict_attributes
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        with self.declare_attributes():
            self.a = 1
            self.b = 2
            self.c = 3
```

So whenever you want to set new attributes, just use the `with` statement as above. It can also be done from outside the instance:

```
a = A()
try:
    a.d = 89
except AttributeError:
    print "It works!"
else:
    print "It doesn't work."
a.c = 42
print a.a
print a.c
with a.declare_attributes():
    a.d = 28
print a.d
```

Comment: @Duncan Good point, but the objective here, according to OP, is to prevent creating new attributes *by accident*. I don't see how anyone can possibly write `a.__dict__['d'] = 89` instead of `a.c = 89` by accident. ;)

Answer (score 4):

> In python, is there a way to prevent adding new class variables after defining the object?

Yes. [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots). But *do* carefully read the notes.

Comment: But that's not the intended use for `__slots__`

Comment: @gnibbler: Sure. But it's a powerful side effect.

Comment: [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) would also be useful if a readonly object is required.

Comment: And if no extra methods are required.

Comment: @jjia6395 OP doesn't want a readonly object. He wants to be able to change existing attributes, but not set new ones by accident. So namedtuple is out, since it's immutable.

Comment: @lazyr yes I am aware of that. Just providing another option for a specific case.

Answer (score 3):

How about a class decorator based on [lazyr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11965077/174728)

```
def freeze(cls):
    _init = cls.__init__
    def init(self, *args, **kw):
        _init(self, *args, **kw)
        self.freeze = True
    cls.__init__ = init 

    def _setattr(self, attr, value):
        if getattr(self, "freeze", None) and (attr=="freeze" or not hasattr(self, attr)):
            raise AttributeError("You shall not set attributes!")
        super(cls, self).__setattr__(attr, value)
    cls.__setattr__ = _setattr

    return cls

@freeze
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3


bar = foo()
try:
    bar.d = 4
except Exception, e:
    print "I want this to always print"
```

Comment: If I had another upvote to give, it would be to you.  Thanks for the clear use class decorators.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `instance.__dict__` to get a dictionary back that lists all of the instance attributes:

```
>>> class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3


>>> bar = foo()
>>> bar.__dict__
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
>>> len(bar.__dict__)  # returns no. of attributes of bar
3
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Preventing adding new attibutes using `__slots__` class attribute:

   ```
   class foo(object):
       __slots__ = ['a', 'b', 'c']
       def __init__(self):
           self.a = 1
           self.b = 2
           self.c = 3

   bar = foo()

   try:
       bar.d = 4
   except Exception as e:
       print(e,"I want this to always print")
   ```
2. Counting attributes:

   ```
   print(len([attr for attr in dir(bar) if attr[0] != '_' ]))
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean new *class* variables or new *instance* variables?  The latter looks like what you mean and is much easier to do.

Per Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer, [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots) is probably what you want.  Just do `__slots__ = ('a', 'b', 'c')` inside of your class and that will prevent any other attributes from being created.  Note that this only applies to instances of your class -- class-level attributes can still be set, and subclasses can add whatever attributes they please.  And he is right -- there are some oddities, so read the linked documentation before you start sprinkling slots everywhere.

If you aren't using slots, `return len(vars(self))` works as a body for your suggested `count` method.

As an alternative to slots, you could define a `__setattr__` that rejects any attribute not on a "known good" list, or to reject any new attributes after a `frozen` attribute is set to True at the end of `__init__`, etc.  This is harder to get right, but more flexible.

If you actually want your instances to be completely read-only after initialization, and you are using a recent version of Python, consider defining a `namedtuple` or subclass thereof.  Tuple subclasses also have some limitations though; if you need to go this route I can expand on it, but I'd stick with slots unless you have a reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you now want your class to have a fixed set of both mutable and immutable attributes?  I've hacked [gnibbler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11965358/566644) to make class attributes immutable after init:

```
def frozenclass(cls):
    """ Modify a class to permit no new attributes after instantiation.
        Class attributes are immutable after init.
        The passed class must have a superclass (e.g., inherit from 'object').
    """
    _init = cls.__init__
    def init(self, *args, **kw):
        _init(self, *args, **kw)
        self.freeze = True
    cls.__init__ = init

    def _setattr(self, attr, value):
        if getattr(self, "freeze", None):
            if attr=="freeze" or not hasattr(self, attr):
                raise AttributeError("You shall not create attributes!")
            if hasattr(type(self), attr):
                raise AttributeError("You shall not modify immutable attributes!")
        super(cls, self).__setattr__(attr, value)
    cls.__setattr__ = _setattr

    return cls
```

And an example:

```
@frozenclass
class myClass(object):
    """ A demo class."""
    # The following are immutable after init:
    a = None
    b = None
    c = None

    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d=None, e=None, f=None):
        # Set the immutable attributes (just this once, only during init)
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        # Create and set the mutable attributes (modifyable after init)
        self.d = d
        self.e = e
        self.f = f
```

Comment: I posted the above from work, where personal logins are not allowed on company systems.  Is there a way I can associate that post with this, my real StackOverflow login?

Comment: Next step: Add iterator support.  Since the attribute set is fixed, we should be able to add many namedtuple capabilities.  Let this decorator create the classy love child of namedtuple and dict.

Comment: The presence of  __init__() seems gratuitous: It's just boilerplate that can be generated.  Why not make a decorator for a function instead?  It would be reminiscent of this comment in an ActiveState recipe (http://code.activestate.com/recipes/500261-named-tuples/#c16).  The function parameters would become the mutable attributes, and locals would become the immutable attributes.

Comment: One more change: Make the python enum metaphor (define a class containing only class attributes) have real const entries if it is instantiated:

Replace:
`_init = cls.__init__`

With:
`if not hasattr(cls, '__init__'): def _init():pass; else: _init = cls.__init__`