# Prevent / alter access to class variables

Tags: python, class-variables

Is there a way to prevent or alter access to class variables in Python as one can via overriding `__setattr__` for instance variables?

Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964895/in-python-count-the-number-of-variables-in-a-class-or-prevent-adding-new-class) is mistitled and actually refers to instance variables, not class variables.

Based on reading multiple posts about the (apparent) deathtrap that is `__slots__`, I'd prefer not to go that route (and I haven't looked into it enough to know if it does what I'm asking).

Example:

```
class A(object):

    foo = "don't change me"

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        raise ValueError

if __name__ == '__main__':
a1 = A()
print a1.foo # don't change me
print A.foo  # don't change me

A.foo = 'bar' # ideally throw an exception or something here
print A.foo   # bar
a2 = A()
print a1.foo  # bar
print a2.foo  # bar
```

Comment: The question linked to by mike has a comment that links to http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property, which might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @mike yep, looks like it is. Dangit. This should probably be closed as a dupe.

Answer (score 6):

Yep! You do it exactly the same way.

A `__setattr__` method on a class controls setting attributes on instances of that class. In Python, everything is an object. And objects have classes. So you just need to arrange for your class to be an instance of some class that has a `__setattr__` method, exactly as you do when you want to prevent instances having their attributes modified!

The class of a class is called a **metaclass**. The default metaclass is `type`: the "type of types", or "class of classes". You want to make a subclass of `type` that doesn't allow its instances attributes to be set (exactly as you make a subclass of `object` that doesn't allow its instances attributes to be set when you're doing this at the instance level).

```
class CantTouchThis(type):
    def __setattr__(cls, attr, value):
        raise Exception("NO!")

class SomeClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = CantTouchThis
```

Note carefully the distinction between the *base class(es)* of `SomeClass`, and the *class* of `SomeClass`. `SomeClass` is a subclass of `object`. It is an instance of `CantTouchThis`.

Almost everything else that works at instance level can be similarly applied to the class level with metaclasses; classes are simply instances like everything else. They only have their distinctive classy behaviour because of the methods and implementation of `type` (exactly as ... etc, etc).

Comment: Does not work in python 3.8

Comment: @NiranjanBhat Instead of the `__metaclass__` dunder in `SomeClass`, use `metaclass=CantTouchThis` in the class signature.

Answer (score 3):

You're nearly there, you just need to move your `__setattr__` method up to the metaclass:

```
class ReadOnlyClass(type):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        raise ValueError(name)
    
class A(object, metaclass=ReadOnlyClass):
    foo = "don't change me"
    
>>> a1 = A()
>>> a1.foo
"don't change me"
>>> A.foo
"don't change me"
>>> A.foo = 'bar'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    A.foo = 'bar'
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 3, in __setattr__
    raise ValueError, name
ValueError: foo
>>> print A.foo
don't change me
>>> a2 = A()
>>> a2.foo
"don't change me"
>>> a2.foo = 'x'
>>> a2.foo
'x'
```

Note that although the metaclass `__setattr__` stops you changing attributes in the class it doesn't stop you hiding them with instance attributes: if that's what you want then you need to define `__setattr__` in both places.

Edit: updated to use Python 3.x syntax instead of ancient Python 2.x

Comment: Does not work in Python3.8

Comment: That's because I wrote it back in 2012 when Python 3 was young and barely used and Python 2 was still going strong. I've edited it to use the Python 3 syntax now.