# Python OOP how to return an object

Tags: python, oop

I'm try to learn OOP in Python. The code below gives you a better idea of what I'm doing. I want to return an object what allows me to call other methods on that data. Is this the right way?

```
content = HTTP().GET(resource="photo/2/")
content.get_image()
```

Class

```
class HTTP(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Creates a new instance of the class and assigns local variables.
        """
        self._resource = None
        self._payload = None
        self._response = None


    @property
    def resource(self):
        return self._resource

    @resource.setter
    def resource(self, value):
        self._resource = "http://api.test.com/" % value


    @property
    def payload(self):
        return self._payload

    @payload.setter
    def payload(self, value):
        self._payload = value


    @property
    def response(self):
        return self._response

    @response.setter
    def response(self, value):
        self._response = value


    def GET(self, resource):
        """
        Sends a GET request. Returns :class:`Response` object.
        :param resource: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
        """
        self.resource = resource
        self.response = requests.get(self.resource).json()
        return self


    def get_image(self):
        """
        Gets raw image from response.
        :return: image
        """
        return requests.get(self.response["raw"])
```

Later I may want to extend this and do

```
content = HTTP().POST(resource="photo/2/", payload='{"somekye":"somevalue"}')
```

or even:

```
content = HTTP().GET(resource="photo/2/")
content.POST(payload='{"somekye":"somevalue"}')
```

Comment: It's the right way, but you should probably return `self.response` instead of `self` if you want to work on the `response` otherwise you have to access it like `content.response.get_image()`.

Comment: Check out [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for a well-done implementation of a HTTP library.

Comment: @Roland Smith try to ignore the requests part this is more about my class and OOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do it this way. You can just modify the 'resource' field, and then simply operate on your instance of HTTP object. Like this:

```
content = HTTP()
content.resource(valueToSet)
content.response(valueToSet)
```

And that's it.

Comment: A lot of examples I see init the values first, which way is better?

Comment: You mean, in the constructor? Yes, it's equivalent to content = HTTP(resource, response) if you change the constructor accordingly (if I understood what you meant)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to read *and* modify an attribute, there is generally no need for getter and setter methods.

A good reason to use properties is e.g. if you need to check the incoming values and possibly raise an exception.

But in that case I would propose you use a method, so that it is obvious to the user that you are executing some code. Because you wouldn't *expect* an exception to occur when modiying an attribute.

If you want to prevent properties from modification, you should use a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359707/prevent-alter-access-to-class-variables).